# I need to get certain values from a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I need to get the specific values like username (only numbers), owner name (after colon), and privileges from the text file which has similar kind of data:

```
Username: A044303                          Owner:  HUMARA_AZIZ_DA_201902
Account:  CORPACCT                         UIC:    [107,713] ([CORPACNT,A044303])
CLI:      DCL                              Tables: 
NETMBX    TMPMBX
Default Privileges: 
  NETMBX    TMPMBX
```

How can I do that using powershell commands ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

- Use `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), to split the content into an array in which property names and their values alternate.
- Process the resulting array via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) to fill an (ordered) [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

You can then directly access the resulting hashtable with property (key) names such as `.Username` (or `['Username']`).

```
$htProps = [ordered] @{}
$i = 0; 
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '((?:Default )?\w+:)' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
  if ($i++ % 2) { $htProps[$propName] = $(-split $_.Trim()) }  
  else          { $propName = $_ }
}
```

Outputting `$htProps` then yields the following (`{...}` indicates that a property contains an *array* of values):

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Username:                      A044303
Owner:                         HUMARA_AZIZ_DA_201902
Account:                       CORPACCT
UIC:                           {[107,713], ([CORPACNT,A044303])}
CLI:                           DCL
Tables:                        {NETMBX, TMPMBX}
Default Privileges:            {NETMBX, TMPMBX}
```

And `$htProps.UserName`, for instance, then returns `A044303`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$test = "Username: A044303 Owner: HUMARA_AZIZ_DA_201902 Account: CORPACCT UIC: [107,713] ([CORPACNT,A044303]) CLI: DCL Tables: NETMBX TMPMBX Default Privileges: NETMBX TMPMBX"

if ($test -match "^Username: [a-zA-Z]([0-9]+) Owner: ([A-Z_]+[0-9]+)") {
   write-host "UserName: "$matches[1]
   write-host "Owner: "$matches[2]   
}
```